# Jordan canonical form linear operators $T$ satisfying (separately) $T^2=T$, $T^2=1$, and $T^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a a linear operator; then I need to find Jordan canonical form of each of the following cases:

1. $T^2=T$.
2. $T^2=1$;
3. $T^2=0$.

For the first and second case I know the eigenvalue are distinct so they are diagonalizable, but the eigenvalues for third one are not distinct so I am not sure. 
How this information will help us finding the Jordan canonical form of each operator?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that the eigenvalues are distinct in the first two cases. For example, if $T=I$.

Comment: What do you mean by $T^2=1$ exactly? Does $1$ refer to the identity on $V$?

Comment: Indeed, in cases (1) and (2) there are only two possible eigenvalues, so the eigenvalues cannot be distinct if $\dim V > 2$.

Comment: Agree.. identity matrix is diagonal ( diagonalizable) and have one eigenvalue ( of multiplicity $n$). thanks for remind me this help me a lot to be aware more about this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** For case (3), an eigenvector $\bf v$ of $T$, say, of eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $$0 = T^2 {\bf v} = T(T {\bf v}) = T(\lambda {\bf v}) = \lambda T {\bf v} = \lambda (\lambda {\bf v}) = \lambda^2 {\bf v},$$
so $\lambda = 0$. So, the only eigenvalue of $T$ is zero.

> Thus, the Jordan canonical form of $T$ is a direct sum $\bigoplus J_{k_a}(0)$ of Jordan blocks of eigenvalue zero. Since $T^2 = 0$, we must have $0 = \left(\bigoplus J_{k_a}(0)\right)^2 = \bigoplus \left(J_{k_a}(0)^2\right)$ and so each Jordan block $J_{k_a}(0)$ must satisfy $$J_{k_a}(0)^2 = 0.$$ But this is only true for Jordan blocks of size $k_a \leq 2$, so the Jordan canonical form of $T$ is a direct sum of blocks $$J_1(0) = \pmatrix{0} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad J_2(0) = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} .$$ On the other hand, any such direct sum has square $0$, so these direct sums are precisely the Jordan canonical forms of linear transformations $T$ satisfying $T^2 = 0$.

Comment: thanks. So third case are not diagonalizable. and also can this be generalized for any nilpotent matrix?

Comment: @henry: Yes, this can be generalized to nilpotent matrices. In fact, this is a common approach to classify the conjugation classes of nilpotent endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. If a matrix satisfying $T^2 = 0$ is diagonalizable, since its only eigenvalue is zero, it is the zero matrix (which is a special but boring case of the above). Like you guess, the analogous argument for general nilpotent matrices goes through, though since we haven't specified a degree of nilpotency we need to allow Jordan blocks $J_k(0)$ of arbitrary size. Indeed, this shows that if a linear transformation $T$ of a finite-dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ is nilpotent, we in fact have $T^n = 0$.